# SSRS report pdf export show column value 0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a cell in a table that value comes form one method which is written in code section of report property as a string type.

In report viewer it's showing the proper value but when I try to export it in PDF that column shows zero in place of the value but in excel and other exports that value export successfully

```
Public total as Decimal=0

Public function CalculateTotalForMaxMarks(m as Decimal) 
    total =total +m
end function   

Public function CalculateTotal() as String 
    return total
end function
```

I would like my output to look like this

```
Value1    Value2   Value3    Total
100       200      200       500
```

Comment: Can you share the current expression / code you are expecting to run?  Perhaps also an example of the underlying data the Code is running against

Comment: Public totalmarks1 as Decimal=0
Public function CalculateTotal(m as Decimal) 
totalmarks1 =totalmarks1 +m
end function   

Public function Sumvalue() as String 
return totalmarks1
end function

Comment: Thanks, and where are these being called?  I assume you have an expression in a cell.  What does this look like?

Comment: =Code.CalculateTotal()

Comment: Well if all you are doing is ever calling `CalculateTotal` then the counter is not being called ever, so the value will remain at 0

Comment: Report viewer it is showing proper value only in pdf export it is howing 0 ,excel also working fine

Comment: Maybe so, but it is still not clear from what you have shown how the function `CalculateTotalForMaxMarks` is ever being called.  Without this information it's difficult to help you with your problem as it stands.  See also my suggestion below to use an alternative to the Custom Code approach

Comment: Every row columns have one max value and one it own value  i want to calculate that all column max value and show it in total max value column

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum across columns is there a reason why you are not simply creating an expression to Sum the values?  Based on the values

```
Value1    Value2   Value3    Total
100       200      200       500
123       456      789       1368
```

You can perform the Expression under total to be

```
=Fields!Value1.Value+Fields!Value2.Value+Fields!Value3.Value
```

To give

[image]

**Edit**

To show a total Max value column you can add a new Row at the bottom of the table, and under Total insert the expression

```
=MAX(Fields!Value1.Value+Fields!Value2.Value+Fields!Value3.Value)
```

You can rename this textbox to be a specific name, in this instance `txtTotalSum`.  You can then add a new Column to your table called Max Total and set the expression of this to be referring to your txtMaxSum value

```
=ReportItems!txtMaxSum.Value
```

Finally to not show the bottom row where the maximum sum is calculated you can hide this row (in the example below coloured blue)

The design would then look like this

[image]

And the output like this

[image]

Comment: Value1,Value2,Value3 and Value4 are not fixed many more may come.

Comment: If the number of Columns you are returning is flexible you should not be returning the data in this manner as it will be **awful** to maintain.  Best practice would instead be returning each row with at Column Id and place this into a matrix instead of a table.

Comment: if i use matrix , any solution ?

Comment: Are you able to edit the query that returns your data?

Comment: Yes i am able to change the query

Comment: Can you then edit the original question with the query you are currently using to generate the output.  I can then try to provide a way to pivot the data for you.

Comment: Yes all are  fine but you are making value field static it's all dynamic it may be 10 or 20 that max query will fail.

Comment: that is original only,